# one question about iostream cout in C++

Tags: c++, iostream, escaping, cout

In such code, what it is called,  `\\n`  like this?

```
cout<<"Hello\\n \'world\'!";
```

What's the basic rule about such characters?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`\n` is an [`escape sequence`](http://www.cppreference.com/wiki/escape_sequences) to print a new line. Now if you want to print a `\n` ( a literal `\n` that is a slash followed by an n) on the screen you need to escape the `\` like `\\`. So `\\n` will make \n print on the screen.

Answer (score 1):

`\n` is a newline character; it signals the end of a line of text.

`\\` is an escaped backslash, so it will print `\`. So `\\n` will just print a literal "\n" to the console.

For more information about C escape sequences, see [Escape Sequences (MSDN)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h21280bw(VS.80).aspx).

Comment: The backslash before `n` is escaped here, so no.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose your question is about escape characters? They are a part of string literal declarations, not stream operations. See [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/69ze775t.aspx) for more details on escape sequences.

In particular: `\n` signifies new line, `\t` signifies TAB character, `\"` signifies a quote character.

Answer (score 1):

In computing, we call those [*escape characters*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_character).